# setBackgroundDrawable is throwing NullPointerException in creating Android Custom ActionBar

Tags: android, exception, android-actionbar

I am getting NullPointerException on setBackgroundDrawable while creating the Custom ActionBar.
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), b));
    actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_view);
```

LogCat results are as follows:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at actionbarcustomview.practice.nkd.actionbarcustomviews.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1931)
```

Line 30 is

```
actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), b));
```

I am using Android Studio and configs are

```
    defaultConfig {
    applicationId "actionbarcustomview.practice.nkd.actionbarcustomviews"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

Please help me to fix this problem.

Comment: Why dont you just Log.d the value of actionBar?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a blog post that should help:

http://blog.perpetumdesign.com/2011/08/strange-case-of-dr-action-and-mr-bar.html

The problem is that `ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();` returns `null`.